# Using react-test-renderer w/ styled-components & Theme (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, styled-components, react-test-renderer, styled-system

I have a `styled-component` that is using `styled-system` and it is working perfectly but when i go to test the component i can't seem to get it to populate the styles correctly from the Theme.

It's strange because if i apply a prop like `marginLeft={1}` this style gets correctly translated from the `Theme.space` property. Is this an issue with the `color` system specifically?

#### Text component

```js
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';
import {
  color,
  space,
  typography,
  variant,
  system,
} from 'styled-system';

const textDecoration = system({ textDecoration: true });
const textDecorationColor = system({ textDecorationColor: true });
const textVariant = variant({ scale: 'text' });
const Text = styled.Text`
  ${textVariant}
  ${textDecoration}
  ${textDecorationColor}
  ${color} <-- using color system
  ${space}
  ${typography}
`;

export default Text;
```

#### test

```js
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';

import Text from '../src/atoms/Text';
import Theme from '../src/theme';

test('Text is referencing Theme (colors)', () => {
  console.log('Theme navy -->', Theme.colors.navy); // Theme navy --> #004175

  const tree = renderer
    .create(
      <ThemeProvider theme={Theme}>
        <Text color="navy" />
      </ThemeProvider>,
    ).toJSON();
  const [styles] = tree.props?.style || {};

  console.log('Post-render color -->', styles.color); // Post-render color --> navy

  expect(styles.color).toBe(Theme.colors.navy);
});
```

```sh
npm run test
...
 ● Text is referencing Theme (colors)

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "#004175"
    Received: "navy"
...
```

Normally i'd test with `color="primary"` which is `#3592fb` but i just get an error stating that `primary` is not a valid value for the style-property `color` which tells me that the `ThemeProvider` is not working correctly.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of [further googling](https://github.com/styled-system/styled-system/issues/1113#issuecomment-615257952) it turns out i should be using the ThemeProvider from `styled-components/native`

```js
// change
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
// to
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components/native';
```